# Oracle Active Data Guard - OPEN_MODE STATUS

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

I would to ask some question regarding Oracle Active Data Guard.

Currently, we are looking for an efficient way to get a real-time backup of Oracle Database. We tried to apply Oracle Active Data Guard on our testing servers running Windows Server 2012 R2 and an unlicensed Oracle 11g R2.

We applied these commands on the Physical Standby Server:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ ONLY;
ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE DISCONNECT FROM SESSION;
```

We checked the `OPEN_MODE` status of the database:

```
SQL> select database_role, open_mode from v$database;
```

We got this as a result:

```
DATABASE_ROLE    OPEN_MODE
---------------- --------------------
PHYSICAL STANDBY READ ONLY WITH APPLY
```

We tried to restart the Oracle Service (to simulate sudden power fluctuation or unintentional server shutdown). The `OPEN_MODE` status becomes:

```
DATABASE_ROLE    OPEN_MODE
---------------- --------------------
PHYSICAL STANDBY READ ONLY
```

Is it by default that the `OPEN_MODE` status became `READ ONLY` if we restart the service? Or do we really need to have a license to fully access Oracle Active Data Guard features so that the `OPEN_MODE` status will remain in `READ ONLY WITH APPLY` permanently even if we restart the Oracle server?

Answer (score 1):

When working with DataGuard, I would strongly advise using the DataGuard Broker (dgmgrl).

It greatly simplifies the cluster management process and is the tool of choice for interrogating and diagnosing problems with the cluster.

```
dgmgrl / 
DGMGRL> show configuration
. . . 
DGMGRL> show database PRIMARY_DB
. . . 
DGMGRL> show database STANDBY_DB
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. No Active Data Guard**

Usually standby database is in *Mount* state and in Recovery mode (applies changes from primary).
Queries to user data will not work because DB is mounted, but not open.
If we want to open db then we have to stop recovery and then open DB.

So archive logs will continue to come but will not apply - the db is unchangeble.
If table was updated on primary - on standby we will not see this changes.

**2. With Active Data Guard**

Usually ADG Standby database is in *Open* state and in Recovery Mode.
And queries return (almost) current data - if table is changed on primary - it is changed on standby.
ADG standby is useful when we want to unload some high load queries(reports) from primary server. If the main reason for Data Guard is HA/DR, then there is no need for ADG license.

When we restart oracle service on windows, it's *open* database.

So run regedit, somewhere like
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_OraDb11g_home1 
change ORA_xxxxx_AUTOSTART to false, where xxxxx - is your oracle instance name.
Now start of service will not start oracle instance.
You need manually, or in script, run

```
startup mount
recover managed standby ...
```

If you set up DataGuard Broker, then there is no need to run the *recover* statement - broker will run it.